# Python script have a problem whith int() convertion whith crontab

Tags: memory, cron, raspberry-pi3, python-3.5

I'm checking memory of my Raspberry pi. It's work's fine.
But when I want run this every minute, crontab says have an error to convert string to int
    *ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''*
My **script.py** :

```
intmemused = 0
cmd = "top -n1 | grep 'Mem :'| awk '{print $6;}'"
output = Popen(cmd,shell=True, stdout=PIPE)
memused = output.communicate()[0].strip()
memused = str(memused.decode("utf-8"))
print(memused) |-----------> 589020
intmemused = int(memused) #Error when crontab execute my scrypt
mem = intmemused * 100
mem = float(mem) / float(memtot)
mem = 100 - float(mem)
mem = round(mem,2)
```

My **crontab** :
`*/1 * * * * /home/dietpi/<b>info.sh</b> 2>/home/dietpi/marseille.log`
My **info.sh** :

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/python3 /home/dietpi/script.py
```

**marseille.log** it create to log errors when it's execute by crontab and in it have :

```
TERM environment variable not set.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/dietpi/config", line 56, in <module>
    intmemused = int(memused)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

When I look this error I've belived ***memused*** is empty but not. Print gived ***589020***
I've belived blank character but I've used **.strip()** 
I've belived TERM environment variable not set. it's a problem, but whith this command ***set | grep TERM*** have a good answer ***TERM=xterm***
I don't undertand why it's work with python3 and not whith crontab
Can you help me ?
Thank's a lot !
MaxKweeger